# Tagging if the client is old or new based on the first date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have here a query that shows three columns:

```
SELECT 
    CLIENT_NO, LOB_CD, 
    TO_DATE(CREATE_DT, 'MMYYYY') AS PURCHASE_DT,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_NOORDER BY CREATE_DT ASC) AS RN  
FROM CLIENTS_T
```

The result is like this:

[image: Query result]

Now, I have to solve this:

- if the client has 2 RN and either purchase date is below 2019, then the tag should be "OLD Client"
- If the client has 1 RN and the purchase date is below 2019, then should still be tagged as "Old Client" else, if the purchase date is above 2019 then should be tagged as "2019 new client" granted that no purchase was done in 2020, 2021 and 2022.
- same goes with 2020, 2021 and 2022. If there are no purchase the prior year, they should be tagged as "NEW".

Is there a way to come up with this?

Here is the desired output:

[image: Desired result]

Thank you.

Comment: don't post images, incorporate tables into your answer instead

Comment: hi @Harry, how do i insert table?

Comment: use table markdown  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT client_no
      ,lob_cd
      ,TO_CHAR(create_dt, 'YYYYMMDD') purchase_dt
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY client_no ORDER BY create_dt) rn
      ,CASE
         -- before 2019
         WHEN MIN(create_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY client_no) 
              < TO_DATE('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           THEN 'OLD'
         -- after 2019 but has an order from a previous year
         WHEN TRUNC(MAX(create_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY client_no), 'YYYY') 
              - TRUNC(MIN(create_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY client_no), 'YYYY') != 0
           THEN 'OLD'
         -- after 2019 with orders in same year
         ELSE
           'NEW'
       END tag
FROM   clients_t
```